# Validating a DMN file is taking lot of time

Tags: drools, dmn

I am creating a DMN with around 43 input fields in a single data type. But when creating a two DMN tables of 26 row items, it is taking lot of time to validate (10 mins +). What can we do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide some code with your question?

Comment: Are you using Business Central? Could you share the DMN model on the drools-usage forum? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-usage